# Sum cells paste final value in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Copy8()
'H0544
Worksheets("PCR AND HPC").Sum(.Range("D3:D5")).Copy
Worksheets("CARE").Range("c25").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End Sub
```

I am trying to sum 3 cells on one sheet and then paste that value in my other sheet

Answer (score 0):

Sum is part of WorksheetFunctions:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("PCR AND HPC").Range("D3:D5"))
```

You can't copy a memory value, just assign it to the output cell:

```
Worksheets("CARE").Range("c25").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("PCR AND HPC").Range("D3:D5"))
```